# How does lazy loading work with the Yandex HtmlElements?

Tags: htmlelements

**Standard WebElement behavior**

Standard WebElement lazy loading works as follows:

```
// Will not try to find button until perform an operation on it such as button.click();
@FindBy(id = "button")
private WebElement button;

// Button list will be created immediately
@FindBy(id = "button")
private List<WebElement> buttons;

// Button list will be created after waiting 5 seconds
@Timeout(5)
@FindBy(id = "button")
private List<WebElement> buttons;
```

**Yandex HtmlElements/TypifiedElement behavior**

Will the following be loaded immediately or lazily loaded when first used?

```
@FindBy(id = "button")
private CustomButton button;        // Extends TypifiedElement

@FindBy(id = "block")
private CustomComponent block;      // Extends HtmlElements
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the same way as standard WebElements - the search for elements will be executed first time when you try access them.

Comment: And if the HtmlElement component has a list or other HtmlElement based components as fields is it still lazy loaded?  List<WebElements> are loaded immediately or if using implicit timeouts will wait for the full duration of the timeout before loading - either way not lazy loaded.  So wondering if these have any impact on the container classes lazy loading...

Comment: Yep, all 'inner' fields of HtmlElement will be lazy loaded.